# Split / explode cell into 2 rows pandas using forward slash as delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, split

I'm trying to split the below dataframe using strg.split.explode, however it isn't working. I'll try my best to be as simple to ask this question.

1. This is my df.

[image]

2. I'm trying to split/explode this DF using delimiter ' / ' (white space + fwd slash + white space) using below code.

`df_excelsb_melt.assign(MOD=df_excelsb_melt['MOD'].str.split(' / ')).explode('MOD')`

3. The result should be in accordance with below table, however it isn't working. Could you please help me achieve this result?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For future references, please paste your data as text. Not pictures.

You can split and explode the `MOD` column before joining it back to the original frame:

```
tmp = df['MOD'].str.split(' / ').explode().to_frame()
result = tmp.join(df.iloc[:, 1:])
```